# How to remove extra spaces from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to retrieve values from database and add it into arraylist .Here is my code ..

```
 ArrayList country = new ArrayList();
 strQuery = "Select * from country";

        rs = conexiondb.Consulta(strQuery);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String toc = rs.getString("country");
            country.add(toc);
        }

        out.print(country);
        System.out.println(country);
        out.close();
```

i have added all the values retrieved from database into country..and here is the values present in the country..

**[APAC, North America, South America, Europe]**

Now as per my need i have to remove space after each comma values and make it like this..

**[APAC,North America,South America,Europe]**

Please guys help me to solve this..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is how `ArrayList` formats it's contents, not the results of your query, try something like...

```
for (String name : country) {
    System.out.println("[" + name + "]");
}
```

To check.  If there are still spaces in the output, then you can use `String#trim` when you extract the values from the database and before you place them in the `List`

If you need to format the `String`, you need to provide you own mechanism, for example...

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add("APAC");
values.add("North America");
values.add("South America");
values.add("Europe");

System.out.println(values);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
for (String value : values) {
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(",");
    }
    sb.append(value);
}
sb.insert(0, "[");
sb.append("]");

System.out.println(sb);
```

Which outputs...

```
[APAC, North America, South America, Europe]
[APAC,North America,South America,Europe]
```

Comment: what about the commas?

Comment: @JunedAhsan The commas are part of how `ArrayList#toString` formats the output

Comment: The commas are part of the format required, and this code doesn't implement it.

Comment: @EJP No (it didn't), it was suppose to show that the output was part of the how `ArrayList` was adding spaces, not a suggestion, but that's now fixed...

Answer (score 1):

You are relying on the default formatting provided by `ArrayList.toString().` Don't do that. Write your own formatting code.

Comment: Or use Guava's [Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) which gives you pretty much all the options you'd ever want in that department.

Comment: OKOK you already said that in your own answer. No need to repeat it everywhere else.

Comment: I didn't, I just repeated it here as an alternative to re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Thus reinventing the wheel of your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The spaces aren't coming from the database at all, they are just a function of the way `ArrayList.toString()` (and in fact all of the JDK Collection classes which inherit from `AbstractCollection`) pretty prints your list.

You can tell this is the case either by looking at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29) for this class, or by noting that there is no space before the initial [.

I recommend [Guava Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) for full control over your output.

```
Joiner.on(',').join(country);
```

will give the `String` you want.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList `toString` method prints the collection using a space after each comma. If you want to print the list without spaces, then you need to write a new method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If memory is not the issue. store it in a separate StringBuilder

This should not be a difficult problem. It is just a bit of manupluation.

In case you want comma separated value to have space storing in arraylist will give you that.

If you need the result to start and end with square braces with inside values being comma separated without any space in between the strings.

```
    ArrayList <String> country = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList country = new ArrayList();
    strQuery = "Select * from country";

    rs = conexiondb.Consulta(strQuery);
    StringBuilder commaSeparated = new StringBuilder("[");

    while (rs.next()) {
        String toc = (rs.getString("country")).trim();
        commaSeparated.append(toc).append(",");
        country.add(toc);
    }

    commaSeparated.append("]");

    out.print(country);
    System.out.println(country);
    System.out.println(commaSeparated.toString());
    out.close();
```