# How to use an arraylist without spaces

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add("APAC");
    values.add("North America");
    values.add("South America");
    values.add("Europe");

System.out.println(values);
```

This will print :

```
[APAC, North America, South America, Europe]
```

Is there a way I can get the output as `[APAC,North America,South America,Europe]` without spaces after `','`. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828447/how-to-remove-extra-spaces-from-arraylist) but it actually uses a `StringBuilder` and all that. Is there an easier way to get this output?

Comment: The question remains....why?

Comment: IF, you had read the [linked question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828447/how-to-remove-extra-spaces-from-arraylist), you would have read *"What you are seeing is how `ArrayList` formats it's contents, not the results of your query, try something like..."*, the extra `, ` is been generated by the `ArrayList#toString` method, you can't and shouldn't care about this.  If you want to display the contents in some other format/way, then you should write code to do that, as was outlined in the linked question/answer...

Answer (score 5):

When you call

```
System.out.println(values);
```

Java will call the `toString()` method on `values`, and output the returned String.

We can call `toString()` manually, and then modify the returned `String` as we would any other. As such, providing ", " doesn't appear in your list, the following should work fine:

```
System.out.println(values.toString().replace(", ", ",");
```

Comment: How do I get the list with the spaces removed? `values.toString().replace(", ", ",")` will return a string!

Comment: The `list` doesn't contain commas, or spaces after commas, they're only occurring in the *output*. Please amend your question to state exactly what you want, I no longer understand

Comment: @Mercenary the list has no spaces! The prinln adds the spaces for printing

Comment: This answer can cause problems if the original dta that is added to the list contains a pattern ", "

Answer (score 2):

With Java8 Stream-API:

```
System.out.println("[" + values.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + "]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [google's guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
System.out.println("["+Joiner.on(",").join(values)+"]");
```

The best place to put this would be in a subclass that override the `toString` method

Answer (score 0):

Create your own class extending `ArrayList` and override `toString()` Method. See

```
AbstractCollection#toString()
```

Comment: Just so you can change the `toString` method for formatting, really isn't a good reason to extend a class, just saying - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, you are right. But I suppose the question was posted with an intention to test some features. Else, this is not supposed to go in real production code. Moreover, a space after a comma is a good practice and checkstyle parser catches it well:)

Answer (score 0):

Extend ArrayList into your own class and override toString() method as your need.

Comment: Extending a class simply to override the `toString` method is a bad reason for extending a class - IMHO

Comment: Yes correct but depends what other options you have.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the easiest solution for this simple case, but in general you might benefit from using some 3rd party collection library for this kind of operations.

Should you wish include Guava to your project this will allow you to rewrite the code above in the following way:

```
Joiner joiner = Joiner.on(",");
List<String> values = ImmutableList.of("APAC", "North America", "South America", "Europe");

String valuesString = joiner.join(values);
System.out.println(valuesString);
```

Also, if you're already using Java 8, then lambda expressions already introduce `mkString` function. See this blog post for good explanation: http://lauer.bz/blog/2013/07/scala-mkstring-in-java-8 on how to use it for collections on your project.